# Is there a ramda function that helps you add logging to piping/composition?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I would like to add logging to a composed chain of functions like so

```
const f = R.compose(
  transformation2,
  doAlso(x => console.log(`id: ${x.id}`)),
  transformation1
)
```

Which would first apply `transformation1` and then log the id of the resulting value before passing it to `transformation2`.

It would be quite easy to implement

```
doAlso = f => x => {
  f(x)
  return x
}
```

But it seems like it should be a quite common pattern. Is this concept called something? Does a similar function exist in FP libs like ramda?

Comment: `const effect = f => x => (f (x), x)` runs effect `f` on `x` and returns `x`

Comment: As Scott said `tap` is what you're looking for, but I wrote [this little snippet](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20logAndPipe%20%3D%20%28...fns%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20log%20%3D%20tap%28console.log%29%0A%20%20return%20pipe%28log%2C%20...intersperse%28log%2C%20fns%29%2C%20log%29%0A%7D%0A%0AlogAndPipe%28%0A%20%20map%28inc%29%2C%0A%20%20zip%28%5B%27two%27%2C%20%27three%27%2C%20%27four%27%2C%20%27five%27%2C%20%27six%27%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20take%282%29%2C%0A%29%28%5B1%2C2%2C4%2C5%5D%29) a while ago that's helped me debug pipe/compose by adding console logs between every step automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is called [`tap`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#tap) in Ramda.